# Javascript Tabber error executing onLoad function

Tags: javascript, tabs

I have a Web page that is using Tabber.js. I would like to be able to link to a page and have it switch to the the correct tab, so that the desired content is displayed.

I've added the following JS code to select the tab (hard-coded to third tab for simplification of the example):

```
function SelectTab() {
    alert("SelectTab started"); /*---- debugging cp1 ----*/
    document.getElementById('myTab1').tabber.tabShow(2);
    alert("SelectTab done");    /*---- debugging cp2 ----*/
}
```

If I add a button to my form to run SelectTab(), it works correctly, and the page switches to the desired tab.  The problem is that I want to have this occur when the page is loaded.  (I cannot use "onload" in the HTML BODY tag, since it tries to run before the tabs have been created, as expected.)  So I want to use the tabber.js "onLoad" option to run the script after the tabs have loaded.  For that, I'm doing the following:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var tabberOptions = {'onLoad':function(){SelectTab();}};
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="tabber.js"></script>
```

Once I do this, my code breaks.  Specifically, I get the error:

```
TypeError: document.getElementById(...).tabber is undefined
```

This occurs in the SelectTab function; the line 'cp1' executes, but not 'cp2'.  However, it's not just the 'onLoad' that's failing; if I have onLoad defined to run that function, then SelectTab also fails when invoked by clicking the button that calls it.

If I change the tabber onLoad option to:

```
var tabberOptions = {'onLoad':function(){alert("Tabber Loaded");}};
```

...then the SelectTab function again works when calling it manually.  I've also tried changing the tabber onLoad option to call a different function, but it still breaks the SelectTab() code.

Any ideas as to why defining a function to execute when tabber.js loads would cause this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up on getting the tabberOptions 'onload' to work. The best I can tell why it's not working: once it's invoked the 'div' defined for tabber tabs is no longer valid.  I did find code in the 'tabber.js' script that removes the parent div "...to prevent a memory leak..." (comment in the code) which seems to prevent tabberOptions and a script manipulating the tabs from coexisting.

So I tried a different approach, which appears to work:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var tabberLoaded = false;
var tabLoadIntervalId = setInterval("SelectTab()", 100);

function SelectTab() {
   if ( tabberLoaded == true ) {
      // alert("SelectTab started"); /*---- debugging cp1 ----*/
      document.getElementById('myTab1').tabber.tabShow(2);
      // alert("SelectTab done");    /*---- debugging cp2 ----*/
      clearInterval(tabLoadIntervalId);
   }
}
```

I modified 'tabber.js' as follows:

```
/* If the user specified an onTabDisplay function, call it now. */
if (typeof this.onTabDisplay == 'function') {
this.onTabDisplay({'tabber':this, 'index':tabberIndex});
}

tabberLoaded = true; /* This is the added line */
return this;
```

Doing this got my page working properly.  I want to do a bit more testing, and make sure I picked the best spot in tabber.js to set the flag.

Answer (score 0):

Try swapping the order of the scripts

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="tabber.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var tabberOptions = {'onLoad':function(){SelectTab();}};
</script>
```

Comment: Swapping the order of the scripts allows the SelectTab() script to work again when run manually, but the onLoad also doesn't execute, so it in effect gives the same behavior as removing the onLoad option.

Comment: Putting the scripts at the bottom of the page ( after </body> ) may help.

Comment: tabber.js is pretty old (2006) Maybe Jquery tabs might be better     http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: Relocating the scripts didn't seem to help.  I tried after </body>, as well as just before it, and after <body...>.

Comment: I took a look at Jquery and may need to consider switching to that if I'm unable to get tabber.js working correctly.  Though I'm hoping to avoid a complete overhaul if I can, esp. since I'm doing this site pro bono.

Answer (score 0):

well, you can change selected tab only when 'tabber' is fully loaded. To be sure everything is loaded use `.load()` event on window in jQuery

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function(){
    document.getElementById('myTab').tabber.tabShow(2);
});
</script>
```

it works like a charm